# Algorithm for matching collection items in python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, search

I'm working on a game program in python. On their turn, a player can purchase a card from a collection of 12 available cards. Each card has a cost consisting of varying quantities of 5 different colored 'gems'. The player has a bank of gems in the same 5 colors (plus gold 'wildcards'). I need to design a method that compares the card costs to the available gems for the player and returns a list of which cards they can purchase.

The obvious solution would be to use brute force, looping through each available card, then looping through each 'color' and comparing it against the player's resources. My end goal with this project however is to use this game to experiment with machine learning. As such, I'm looking to optimize anything that is going to be called frequently. I feel like there is a more efficient solution but I'm not sure what that would be.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can also do efficient comparison of values by using 1D NumPy arrays instead of lists. Ex: `a = np.array([1,7,3,4,9]); b = np.array([2,6,6,7,3]); a > b` yields `array([False,  True, False, False,  True])`. Not an ML approach, but if you're doing a lot of these comparisons it could make your code cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: Only 12 cards? You're going to have a hard time beating brute force.

Answer (score 1):

If you had many more cards then I'd suggest you put your data in a trie that can be searched efficiently.  So instead of having to check, say, red gems over and over again, you stop at each possible number of red gems and then look through the rest of the conditions from there.

It isn't hard to write that code, and it would run just fine for 12 cards.  But my bet is that for just a dozen cards and 5 colors of gems, it would run much more slowly than a brute force approach.  Particularly if brute force was micro-optimized through using something like `numpy` or running under PyPy.